# Laravel: Event Listener - Argument 1 passed to {closure}() must be of the type array, object given

Tags: php, laravel

I hope this question is not duplicated.

I have the following event defined:

```
Event::listen('test', function(array $data){
    dd($data);
});
```

---

When I attempt to fire it, I receive the below exception:

```
event('test', [
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'asdf' => 'ghjk',
]);
```

> TypeError:
>
> Argument 1 passed to {closure}() must be of the type array, object given

---

However if I execute it the following way, problem does not occur:

```
event('test', [[
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'asdf' => 'ghjk',
]]);
```

---

Question: if I want to pass a strict array to the listener closure, is there a way to avoid the wrapping of my var in another array?

Comment: If you avoid typehinting it, what does dd($data); print?

Comment: In first case I receive 'bar'. In second case I receive the whole array ['foo' => ... ]

Comment: I had deleted and undeleted my answer after digging into it. Let me know if you want any further clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging into the framework a bit I think I have found the "problem".

The array you are passing into your listener is supposed to be the arguments of the callback. ie)

```
Event::listen('test', function($foo, $bar, $baz) {
    dd($foo, $bar, $baz);
});

event('test', ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']);
```

When you pass an array to the event() helper it will ultimately call makeListener in Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher to execute your closure. And in that method it calls your listener as follows:

```
    return $listener(...array_values($payload));
```

So the reason why:

```
event('test', [[
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'asdf' => 'ghjk',
]]);
```

Works, is because:

```
...array_values([[
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'asdf' => 'ghjk',
]])
```

is simply ['foo' => 'bar', 'asdf' => 'ghjk']

Hope that helps! One of those things that is just about finding the right documentation!

So to answer your ultimate question:

"Question: if I want to pass a strict array to the listener closure, is there a way to avoid the wrapping of my var in another array?"

No :(